# Использование функций javascript из стороннего файла

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Изучаю js и пока что многого не понимаю. Есть проект mvc. В нём используется ajax запрос. И по результату запроса либо в случае успеха либо в случае ошибки выполняется функция. Если я напишу прям в самом ajax запросе функции всё работает. Попробовал написать в стороннем файле и всё пошло немного не так как я предполагал. Вот код стороннего файла с функциями:

```
$(function successFunc (data) {
    alert('Успех');
    $('#results').html(data);
});

$(function errorFunc(xhr) {
    alert(xhr.status + 'Ошибка');
});
```

В layout подключается сам файл:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/Result.js")
```

Вот код view с ajax запросом:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<div>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="txt" />
    <input type="button" id="btn" class="edit" value="Отправить" />

    @section scripts {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#btn').on('click', function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Home/BookSearch",
                    data: { "name": $('#txt').val() },
                    success: successFunc(data),
                    error: errorFunc(xhr)
                });
            });
        </script>
    }

    <div id="results"></div>

</div>
```

В итоге обе функции выполняются сразу же при запуске приложения. А как сделать так что бы они выполнялись только по результату ajax запроса как это и предполагается?

Код с функциями внутри view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<div>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="txt" />
    <button id="btn">Отправить</button>

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("BookSearch", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "results" }))
    {
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="submit" value="Поиск" />
    }

    @section scripts {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#btn').on('click', function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Home/BookSearch",
                    data: { "name": $('#txt').val() },
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert('Успех');
                        $('#results').html(data);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        alert(xhr.status + 'Ошибка');
                    },

                });
            });
        </script>
    }

    <div id="results"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы передаётся свои функции в фурнцию `$`, которая их сразу выполняет. А нужно просто их объявить:

```
function successFunc (data) {
    alert('Успех');
    $('#results').html(data);
}

function errorFunc(xhr) {
    alert(xhr.status + 'Ошибка');
}
```

Comment: Nick спасибо большое, заработало, функции видит, но ошибка на строчке `success: successFunc(data),` Почему то не определяет дату, хотя если у меня функции в этой же вьюхе написаны то всё работает, подскажите пожалуйста что не так, добавляю 2 вариант кода с фукнкциями внутри view в вопрос.

Comment: Nick возможно в случае когда функция находится в другом файле нельзя в неё передавать с помощью слова data? Потому что я попробовал передать  функцию вместо слова data, $('#txt').val() и в функцию код зашёл, но в таком варианте у меня код в контроллер не идёт, как будто ajax запрос не завершается.

Comment: @Андрей, попробуйте так `success: successFunc`

Comment: Nick спасибо уже разобрался по примерам из сети, забыл отписаться. А подскажите пожалуйста если у меня функция с входными параметрами а я вызываю её и ничего не передаю как она подтягивает эти самые входные параметры? Ajax запрос каким то Макаром передаёт их туда?

Comment: Nick? Можете ответить на последний вопрос который я написал?

Comment: @Андрей Если вы пишете `success: successFunc`, то функцию `successFunc` вызываете не вы, а jQuery после выполнения запроса. Вернее jQuery вызывает функция указанную в поле `success` с тремя параметрами: `Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR`

Comment: Nick спасибо за разъяснение.